# W5100: get MAC address from devices in network?

Tags: arduino, ethernet, mac

I'm using a single [Arduino Ethernet Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield) with an [Wiznet W5100 chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/Arduino/W5100_Datasheet_v1_1_6.pdf) to scan a network for all devices. ([Find the project source code on Github](https://github.com/powtac/Autarc_LAN_User_Stats)).

All devices are in the same Ethernet segment. They are connected to a standard consumer router. They all were assigned to IP addresses in a range of 10.0.1.0 - 10.0.1.20. The goal is to identify devices in the same network, even if the IP has changed and to protocol when a device is online.

I was researching on this problem for weeks and I have not found anything useful on the Internet. This is the only piece of code I have found so far: http://mbed.org/users/va009039/code/w5200NetIf/file/a8df39b4f3aa/MyNetUdpSocket.cpp, line 124 `W5100.readSnDHAR(_socket, mac)` but it does not work.

Is it even possible to get a MAC address for a found device (IP is known then) in the same network?

Comment: Have you thought about broadcast packets? Whether that will work does depend on the network topology a fair bit. But each device could just periodically send a packet with its MAC address and each node could build a table of MAC versus IP address.

Comment: How can I ask devices to send their MAC address?

Comment: Actually I might have misunderstood, I was thinking every node would be an Arduino + W5100 so your code could retrieve it from the module and broadcast it to other nodes. But that won't work if the other devices aren't things you can program yourself.

Comment: @PeterJ, thanks for responding, I updated the description.

Comment: What type of network? MAC address is ethernet specific, are all nodes on the same ethernet segment?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen all devices are in the same Ethernet segment. They are connected to a standard consumer router. They all were assigned to IP addresses in a range of 10.0.1.0 - 10.0.1.20. The goal is to protocol when a device is online.

Comment: If you've got the CPU time you could check all ethernet messages, collect their source MACs, and declare a device present if it had any activity in the last X seconds.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. You're reading the correct register, but you might not have the W5100 in the correct state at the time you're reading it. You're going to have to show us your source code, and please reduce it to the smallest example that demonstrates the problem. For example, are you using "MAC raw" mode? See page 57 of the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/Arduino/W5100_Datasheet_v1_1_6.pdf).

Comment: OK, I finally found the relevant code in your Github project. Have you tried asking [Blake Foster](http://www.blake-foster.com/) about this, since it's his code you're hacking?

Comment: from a command line it would work like `arp HP5180.local` where HP5180.local is my printer, but can be any IP-address on the network.
`Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface` followed by
`HP5180.local             ether   02:0f:b5:52:73:65   C                     eth0`. So what you have to do is use the [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) protocol.

Comment: @DaveTweed thank you for your suggestions and your research. I have not yet asked Blake Foster.

Comment: I found a solution: https://github.com/powtac/Autarc_LAN_User_Stats/blob/master/autarc_lan_user_stats/autarc_lan_user_stats.ino see function "pingDevice"

Answer (score 2):

Here are few pointers:

1. [SSDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol)
2. [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPNP)
3. [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en) or equivalent tool.

Also, Lantronix has a protocol for discovering their embedded devices, you might want to look there.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if you'd add some text explaining why each of these links is relevant to the question. Keep in mind that the question is specific to the W5100.

Comment: Exactly the functionality that Fing offers, I want to "copy"!